# .htaccess: remove random number and hyphen from a url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am wondering to remove random number with hyphen from URL and redirect to rest URL using .htaccess file

for example,
I have a following URL and I want to remove "16-" from it

https://example.com/pics/16-Apple_8xx.jpg

Expected URL and redirection to:

https://example.com/pics/Apple_8xx.jpg

Please help me to get rid out of this problem. 
Sorry, No prior experience in .htaccess files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research and understanding with the .htaccess configurations 
I got my answer globally for both localhost and live domain.

Now, simply my .htaccess file consist of following code lines.

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 [\d]+-(.+)$ http://localhost/redirect/pics/$1
```

For live domains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 [\d]+-(.+)$ http://example.com/pics/$1
```

Thank you so much @arkascha for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?pics/[\d]+-(.+)$ /pics/$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

UPDATE:

In your comment to this question you now wrote another path than you wrote in your question. In the comment I explained what then the rule will not get applied. So either you need to make pattern and target match the actual requirement:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?redirect/pics/[\d]+-(.+)$ /redirect/pics/$1 [R=301]
```

Or you can *try* to implement a more flexible rule. This however often is the cause of surprising side effects you only find out much later. So this is questional:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /pics/[\d]+-(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*pics)/[\d]+-(.+)$ /$1/%1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. unfortunately, It's not working as I am testing on localhost.
I am hitting URL http://localhost/redirect/pics/65-1.jpg
and pics folder contains http://localhost/redirect/pics/1.jpg 
image 1.jpg.

Comment: Its giving me Object not found!

Comment: Sure, `/redirect/pics/65-1.jpg` is something different than `/pics/65-1.jpg`... In your question you wrote the path is `/pics/.....`, here now you suddenly have an additional `/redirect/...` preceding that path. That is why the pattern does not match. You will need to either add that additional path part to pattern and target, or risk a less precise matching which may cause side effects later.

Comment: can you please help me in both cases?

Comment: Unfortunately, Update answer is not working ;(
http://localhost/redirect/pics/16-1.jpg 
I hit this URL in which *16* could be any random number with hyphen -
Redirection should be at following link after removal of both random number and hyphen
http://localhost/redirect/pics/1.jpg 

@arkascha please help me to fix this issue in both localhost and live URL
Thanks again!

Comment: I do have to apologize, indeed all three variants contained a trivial issue: the `+` for capturing what you call a "random number" has to be placed _outside_ the square brackets, obviously. I fixed the answer and confirmed that the rules actually work now as expected. Please note however that you are expected to not just blindly copy suggestions from here. You are expected to be a developer yourself, to understand what you copy and to be able to adapt it...